# Removing the underlying polygons to only get the top polygon

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geoprocessing, suitability-analysis

I'm trying to do a suitability analysis in ArcGIS Pro but I've seem to run into a problem with overlaying polygons that shouldn't be overlaying. I put all the data into a weighted sum and then divided the weighted Sum into 11 different "classes" using raster calculator. I should then get the areas of all classes perfectly alligned next to each other but they aren't (as shown in the foto's).

[image: Layers without top layer]

[image: Layers with top layer]

[image]

I'm trying to only get the top layer if it overlaps with the layers beneath but I can't seem to figure out how. Does anybody know how to do this?